# Pass data from json to variable express nunjucks

Tags: json, node.js, express, nunjucks

This is one of those questions that have been asked a few times but still has no good answers. I cant work out how to retrieve my data in stored in seperate json files for use by the variables i define in my partials and macros. Note I am trying to achieve this without gulp or grunt, just node if if possible.

Finding a clear solution has been very difficult. Can anyone assist?

Comment: Did you try something as simple as this `res.render('view-name', {my_variable: require('my_json_file.json'));` and in nunjucks use `<p>{{ my_variable }}</p>`

Comment: No will try it out. Thanks.

Comment: @molda I'm having trouble understanding how to use this. If I have a json with 20 variables and I want to be able to use any of those variables in any view how would I make them globally available? For example something like: res.render('view1.njk', {all-the-variables: require('variables.json'));res.render('view2.njk', {all-the-variables: require('variables.json'));

then in view1.njk: <p>{{var1}}</p> <p>{{var2}}</p> <p>{{var3}}</p> and view2.njk <h1>{{var1}}</h1>

Comment: Assuming variables.json looks like this {"val1": "hello"} render -> res.render('view2.njk', {vars: require('variables.json')}); the view -> <h1>{{ vars.val1 }}</h1>

Comment: cheers mate will give it a go. just woke up. how the heck do you get started with this it seems like theres no info out there! Ive got an open question about this, if you want to anawer it I can mark you right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41800188/nunjucks-retrieve-data-from-variables-in-json-file-npm-only

Comment: @molda 
    'router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('index.njk', {vars: require('vars.json')});
});'  result in browser: Error: template not found: error.nunjucks. When I remove the vars:require part it works fine?

Comment: FINALLY GOT IT!!!! YES. THANK YOU. My file path was incorrect : P