# Nunjucks: Retrieve data from variables in json file (npm only)

Tags: javascript, nunjucks

I posted a similar question recently but did not get enough of a response to understand my problem. It seems like a question that gets asked a lot but never really answered properly.

Using npm only (no gulp or grunt) with nunjucks how do you access the variables you define in a json file for use in your views when precompiling?

Scenario:

```
VIEWS
view1.njks: <h1>{{var1}}
view2.njks: <h1>{{var1}},  <h2>{{var2}}
view3.njks: <h1>{{var2}}

DATA
variables.json: var1: red, var2: blue.

CONFIG
app.js: path to variables.json and ability to access data globally in any view, block etc.
```

Hopefully this is enough info to convey my issue, please let me know if you would like me to clarify anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that may come across this the solution, add

```
data_variable: require('../data.json')
```

to your route in the index.js file for each page of your site that needs data from a json file.

eg.

```
/* GET view1. */
router.get('/view1', function(req, res) {
        res.render('view1.njk', {
             data_variable: require('../variables.json')});
});
```

Comment: it tells me "cannot find module 'data.json'" ??